# Git Merge: What do the pluses mean?

Tags: git, github, merge, diffstat

I ran "git merge" from Terminal on Mac OS X to merge a branch into my master and receive output that looks like:

```
 spec/models/user_spec.rb    57 ++++++++++++++++++++
```

What does the "57 ++++++++++++++++++++" mean? Is that how many times I inserted/modified that file? What are all the plusses for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

57 lines changed.  The pluses are graphical indications of the number of lines changed, kind of like a bar chart.  They make more sense when you have changed several files, as they give a quick way to see the relative amount of lines changed per file.

I've found that if you only make a few changes, each plus corresponds to one line.  As you make more, it scales them back.

It also shows minuses for line deletions.

If you made 28 (57/2) line changes in another file, you would see a string of pluses half as long next to it.

Comment: To be precise, these are line-by-line changes, so that's 57 added lines.

Answer (score 2):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13763549/1031900):

It supposed to reflect the amount of changes (in lines) of each file listed.
Plus signs for additions, minuses for deletions.

The *57* gives the amount of changed lines, and the *-* / *+* gives you the proportion of deletions/additions.
When the amount of changes can fit a line you'll get '*+*' per addition, '*-*' per deletion;
Otherwise, this is an approximation, e.g.

```
CHANGES.txt     |   47 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
make-release.py |   77 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------
2 files changed, 102 insertions(+), 22 deletions(-)
```

On `CHANGES.txt` since you can see that there are no '*-*', and since 47 '*+*' are a lot you have a proportionate amount of them (i.e. 100%).
On `make-release.py` you'll see *x39* '*+*' standing for 55 additions and *x16* '*-*' standing for 22 deletions.
Exactly as their proportion, and just the amount to fit output screen.

The amount of signs per line the a `GCD` multiple that fits the line width.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In complement to other answers: this is the `diffstat` syntax, not just a Git thing. Git shows the diffstat after a merge, or when you ask for it like `git diff --stat` which produces roughly the same output as `git diff | diffstat`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes - there were 57 changes to that file and they were all additions.